# Deploying Solid.JS+Railway 404 not found issue on page refresh

Tags: cloud, devops, vite, solid-js, railway

Okay so I've been at this pretty much all day and I have no idea what to try and do to get this to work. On the Solid.JS Docs for deploying on Railway it says to add this line to your package.json so that it runs properly in production

```
"start": "npx http-server ./dist",
```

On Railway I configured my build and my start commands and everything works great except for when I want to refresh or navigate directly to a path that isn't the root in which case it just returns a 404 not found.

Now after doing some digging I found that I should add a proxy flag to route all requests preventing the 404 not found from happening and this method works locally!

```
npx http-server ./dist --port 8080 -P http://localhost:8080?
```

Now the problem with this is that Railway is running on https though so it does not work on there unfortunately. I know there's a way to have it run on https though by passing in another flag and specifying the path of the cert.pem but I'm not sure where that is on Railway so I'm just completely lost on what to do. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue, I initially thought it was a `solid.js` bug but it's rather a `vite` issue, you just need to create a `json` file named `vercel.json` at the root of your project folder(I use `Vercel`, I don't know any equivalent to that for `Raleway` but I hope you'll figure it out). The contents of the `vercel.json` will be:

```
{ "routes": [{ "src": "/[^.]+", "dest": "/", "status": 200 }] }
```

This fixed my problem, hope it fix your's too.